# Aws TTS Polly -> How to check current usage (number of chars already used)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, limit, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I want to know how can I check my current usage of Amazon Polly.

I'm currently on free tier, so I could not find any information on billing since I still haven't surpassed the 3 million characters per month.

But I wanted to have a control of how many characters I'm using daily, so I can calculate how much I will be spending in the future, when my free tier ends.
For development too it is necessary for me.

And is there a way to limit how many chars I want to use per month? So I won’t have problems later?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Menu -> AWS Cost and Usage Reports -> AWS Usage Report -> Amazon Polly
...and filter as you need

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).